# My widget doesn't seem to want to execute HttpGet from a HttpResponse

Tags: android, httpresponse, android-appwidget, http-get, onupdate

Here is my onUpdate code.

```
    ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context,
            MyWidgetProvider.class);
        int[] allWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);
      final int N = appWidgetIds.length;



  for ( int ii = 0; ii < N ; ii++)
  {
  RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
            R.layout.widget_layout);
  Toast.makeText(context, "Loading", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.update, "Loading2");


 try {
    data = connect();
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}


    now = Calendar.getInstance();
    timeHour = now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.update, "The latest PSI reading is " + data);



Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyWidgetProvider.class);

intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
    0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.update, pendingIntent);

appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(allWidgetIds, remoteViews);

  }
```

}

And here is the method for connect();

```
public String connect() throws IOException
{       String temp = "WAD";

    try {
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpGet get = new HttpGet("http://app2.nea.gov.sg/anti-pollution-radiation-protection/air-pollution/psi/psi-readings-over-the-last-24-hours");

    HttpResponse response;


        response = client.execute(get);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        InputStream in = entity.getContent();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){

            sb.append(line+"\n");


        }
        in.close();
        temp = sb.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return temp;



}
```

The thing is my code seems to die at

response = client.execute(get);

According to what LogCat was telling me. It pointed out the tag "System.err" at that line, and at data=connect();

The connect() method worked well on other apps, not widgets, so I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

EDIT:

Here is the logcat.

06-27 21:30:38.058: W/System.err(28060):    at com.example.psi.MyWidgetProvider.connect(MyWidgetProvider.java:284)
06-27 21:30:38.058: W/System.err(28060):    at com.example.psi.MyWidgetProvider.onUpdate(MyWidgetProvider.java:71)
06-27 21:30:38.058: W/System.err(28060):    at android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider.onReceive(AppWidgetProvider.java:66)

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace, usually the answer lies in it.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I found the solution,

It was to enter the StrictMode threadpolicy,

```
  StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
  StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

I know this is not the best way to do this, but I was doing a proof of concept and not trying to make this app smooth.